# Alternative XPath suggestion needed

Tags: selenium, xpath

First off, I am really overwhelmed by capabilities of XPath and I am trying to learn it.

I need to write XPath to be used in Selenium to locate Depart date on this website: [Link](https://www.yatra.com/) , and I tried something like this to find "March 30".

`//div[text()='March']/../div[contains(@id,'PegasusCal-0')]//span[text()='30']`

Above XPath is working fine for year 2017 and 2018, but still I feel that there are other ways to write this XPath using the real XPath capabilities and make it more generic. My requirement is to write XPath such that it passes for any year or so.

Please suggest me. This way I will get to learn about it more.

Comment: `.//a[@id='a_2017_3_30']/span` This will work

Comment: @aiaa what exactly are you trying to achieve if you have to click on date, in particular year and month, the xpath suggest by kishan will work perfectly.  or you click directly on link using ID,  a_2017_3_30?

Comment: It's not unique. It has 7 matching nodes. Also, I am avoiding to include year in my XPath.

Answer (score 0):

What probably you can do is, you can create a generalize Xpath for whatever value you want to input:

You can save your date in three variables:

**year: 2017**

**month: 3**

**day: 30**

`findElement(By.xpath(".//a[@id='a_" + year + "_" + month + "_" + day + "']/span");`

If suppose your year is fixed as 2017 then :

`findElement(By.xpath(".//a[@id='a_2017_" + month + "_" + day + "']/span");`

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Kishan's answer. It seems that there are several elements with id 'a_2017_3_30' in the page. So we have to limit the scope of where we're looking for it. Or we could also make the limiter in such a way that we can provide a variable.

`//div[starts-with(@id,'PegasusCal') and div[contains(text(),'Depart')]]//a[@id='a_2017_3_30']`

so let's make the texts 'Depart', '2017', '3', and '30' all variables to a method.

```
public void selectDateForDateField(int year, int month, int day, String dateField) {
    browser.findElement(By.xpath("//div[starts-with(@id,'PegasusCal') and div[contains(text(),'" + dateField + "')]]//a[@id='a_" + year + "_" + month + "_" + day + "']"));
}
```

so you can use this as:
`selectDateForDateField(2017,3,30,"Depart")`
`selectDateForDateField(2018,4,24,"Return")`